# INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY doesnt refresh/delete the data if the result is 0 records

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, beeline

Here is my query

> insert overwrite directory '/myloc/output' select *from emp where eid < 123;

I have got some records in the '/myloc/output' location, 
Now again I run the below query..

> insert overwrite directory '/myloc/output' select *from emp where eid > 345;

If there are **no records** satisfying the condition eid > 345 then the results are 0 records. In that case, beeline will not delete the old data (ie., eid < 123).

**Is there a way to tell beeline that, delete/refresh the directory even though there are no records satisfying the condition**.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug which is fixed on later versions. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13997

As workaround you can delete the files under directory manually before your insert overwrite statemente (not the ideal but do the job)